# Package alsa was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `alsa.pc'

Tags: alsa, debian, rust

im having problems with bevy framework.

sorry im new at this site and idk how to make my question more "readable"
Full exit code when i try to run:`cargo run --example hello_world`

- I tried locate `alsa.pc` -> return nothing.
- some code is in the same line because i dont know how to breakline "\n" here :c

```
#########################################################################################

   Compiling alsa-sys v0.3.1 
   Compiling libudev-sys v0.1.4
error: failed to run custom build command for `alsa-sys v0.3.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/root/plib/Download/bevy/target/debug/build/alsa-sys-15ce9f331cc5c6c6/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ALSA_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ALSA_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ALSA_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '`"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "alsa"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  error: could not find system library 'alsa' required by the 'alsa-sys' crate

  --- stderr
  Package alsa was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `alsa.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'alsa' found
  ', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/alsa-sys-0.3.1/build.rs:13:18
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
#########################################################################################
```

Comment: oh dear i mean cargo run --example hello_world

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; but have tagged it's related to a Debian-Ubuntu packaging workflow without making that clear.  Please provide details & clarify.

Comment: Ohhh you right, sorry im not home rn tomorrow i update. But is parrot Os v5

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 10):

To get needed *alsa.pc* file you have to find the [corresponding package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=alsa.pc)  and then install it by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

and also

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

and then retry.

Follow https://bevyengine.org/learn/book/getting-started/ if unsure what to do.

Comment: Installing only the `libasound2-dev` package was enough for me. I have rustc 1.73.0 version on Debian 12.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks @N0rbert !